# Catch a JavaScript error from a upper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, try-catch

I'm stuck with the following problem:

```
function upperFn(){
    FetchSomeThing() 
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err) 
    })
}

function lowerFn(){
    try {
        upperFn()
    }
    catch (err){
        //Here its not working anymore
        console.log(err) // Catch is never used
    }
}
```

So I've tried to return the error and even rethrow it but nothing work's.
I would be very happy if someone can explain me how to catch this error in my lower function.

Thanks

Comment: Make `upperFn` return the promise, and then handle the promise rejection. You cannot handle asynchronous errors with a synchronous `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out how to handle this probleme, simply by returning the whole function.

```
function upperFn(){
    return FetchSomeThing()
}

function lowerFn(){
    try {
        upperFn()
    }
    catch (err){
        //Here its working well
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't part of the point of promises to avoid *try..catch* (which id decidedly ugly), hence [*Promise.prototype.catch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply `throw` the error in `upperFunction` and try-catch it in the `lowerFunction`

```js
function FetchSomeThing() {
  return Promise.reject("Something goes wrong.");
}

function upperFn(){
  FetchSomeThing().catch(error => {
    throw error;
  })
}

function lowerFn(){
  try {
      upperFn()
  }
  catch (error) {
      //Here its not working anymore
      console.log(error) // Catch is never used
  }
}

lowerFn()
```

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-thunder-3s9qj

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me, it's sending me this err: Uncaught (in promise), but in my case the FetchSomeThing function is a firebase function that I can change

Comment: ` err: Uncaught (in promise)` means there is an error but you don't catch it, can you please show me your code? 

Also the code in your question is not correct, it should be like this: `  FetchSomeThing()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-haze-v6c80?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Please try this one:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-noyce-w8czu

Comment: This way is working thanks for the time!

Comment: @LaurentK you're welcome, I'm gonna update the original answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you missed the `error` param after catch?

```
try {
  doSomeThing();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: I was not missing the err in my real code, but I have found a way to solve my problem